# Aggregate custom data from ParallelQuery

Tags: c#, aggregate, plinq

I'm parsing a lot of words (millions) from some files and counting them by language. I'm using PLINQ because performance, but I think (by watching Task Manager), that whole process going sequential. Probably blocked by my aggregate function.

Is that possible?

Here is incriminated PLINQ

```
ParallelQuery<string> query = Directory.EnumerateFiles(test, "*.d", SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsParallel();
query = query.SelectMany(parseStrings).Where(isValidPhrase);
query = query.SelectMany(s => Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value));

Result output = query.Aggregate(new Result(), (result, word) =>
{
    if (word.All(russianAlfabet.Contains))
        result.Ru++;
    else if (czechWords.Contains(word))
        result.Cs++;
    else
        result.Other++;

    return result;
});
```

...and this is a class for aggregated result

```
class Result {
    public int Ru { get; set; }
    public int Cs { get; set; }
    public int Other { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this overload for [ParallelEnumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383667(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
public static TResult Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(
    this ParallelQuery<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> updateAccumulatorFunc,
    Func<TAccumulate, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> combineAccumulatorsFunc,
    Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector
)
```